# Mediaelement.js: Show controls panel on click the video

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins, mediaelement.js

I would like to show the "controls" panel only on click (play-event) the video.

I've already hidden the ".mejs-controls":

**CSS**

```
.mejs-controls{ visibility:hidden; }
```

and set the folowing:

**JS**

```
$('video,audio').mediaelementplayer({
    alwaysShowControls: true,
    success: function (mediaElement, domObject) {
        mediaElement.addEventListener('play', function(e) {
            $('.mejs-controls').css("visibility", "visible");
        }, false);
    }
});
```

And it works for me, BUT if I have more than one player on page it shows the controls in every player on this page. How can I avoid this and show the controls only in player that I've clicked?

**UPDATE**

The **HTML** is simple:

```
<div class="video-wrapper">
                    <video src="images/video/video.mp4" poster="images/video/poster.jpg"></video>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the HTML structure you use.

So your issue is that you're targeting all the `$('.mejs-controls')` instead of  (here in example since you did not show any HTML) only the one that is related to `$(this)`

```
$(this).closest("div").find('.mejs-controls').css("visibility", "visible");
```

so it's all about figuring out the needed **DOM traversal method** - in order to get the right element but always referring to the `this` interacting one.

Comment: Unfortunatly your suggestion doesn't work. (and there is no error in the console)

Comment: @ChopChop ...can you please show your `.mejs-controls` in your HTML? Where are they? Hope it's not a secret... ;)

Comment: Thanks Roko for your hint. I've got it now. Mediaelement.js is wrapping around the video tag in an extra div and .mejs-controls was neighbour tag. 
The solutin is:

$(this).parent().nextAll('.mejs-controls').css('visibility', 'visible');